# Displaying multiline JLabels in custom console?

Tags: java, string, swing, jframe, jlabel

I was working on a custom console for a game I'm working on but when it attempts to display long messages it adds ".." at the end and doesn't display the whole message, the dimensions of the JFrame are 720x480, and here is the code without calculation:

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    JLabel label = new JLabel(line, SwingConstants.LEFT);
    label.setBounds(5, currentLine*15, 720, 15);
    label.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 15));
    frame.add(label);
    frame.repaint();
    currentLine++;
}
```

and here is it but with calculation:

```
 while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    JLabel label = new JLabel(line + " AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", SwingConstants.LEFT);
    double textWidth = label.getMaximumSize().getWidth();
    int lineSize = 1;
    lineSize = (int) Math.ceil(textWidth / 720);
    System.out.println(lineSize); // prints 2

    label.setBounds(5, currentLine*20, 720, lineSize*20);
    label.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(720, lineSize*20));
    label.setFont(ConsoleFont);
    frame.add(label);
    frame.repaint();
    currentLine += lineSize;
}
```

but the difference is that with calculation it increased JLabel size but doesn't do to it's text

Comment: JLabel [has already calculated that height](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getPreferredSize%28%29).

Comment: How do I get it?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the (external file and) input stream. 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). ..

Comment: .. 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Answer (score 1):

JLabel already knows the size necessary to display its content.  That size is returned by [getPreferredSize](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getPreferredSize%28%29).

You wouldn’t have to figure out positions and sizes yourself, if you use a LayoutManager.  In your case, a [vertical Box](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Box.html#createVerticalBox%28%29) probably would be sufficient:

```
private Box linesContainer = Box.createVerticalBox();

private Font linesFont = new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 15);

// ...

    frame.add(linesContainer);

// ...

    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(line, SwingConstants.LEFT);
        label.setFont(linesFont);
        linesContainer.add(label);

        // Add spacing.
        linesContainer.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(3));
```

Here’s another good reason to use a LayoutManager:  You don’t know how many pixels high a 15 point font actually is on other people’s computers.  15 points doesn’t mean 15 pixels; it means ¹⁵⁄₇₂ inch, and how many pixels are needed to display that will depend on the dot pitch of the user’s monitor.

You *could* try calculating that yourself, but Swing already does all that work if you let a LayoutManager, like the one used internally by Box, do its job.

(Also notice that I moved the creation of the Font outside of the loop.  Creating new, identical Font objects wastes memory.)

Comment: Didn't work, I tried to calculate height and it worked but the text still had .. at the end

Comment: Can you share an example of text which causes that problem?

Comment: It's simply a line of text but I combined a long "AAA..." text to test it

Comment: Did you hard code the bounds of the Box?  Perhaps making it wider will help?

Comment: I increased the size of each line to 20 but kept the font at 15

Comment: and yes it now displays it in 2 lines (2*20) but the text is centered and doesn't display in both of the lines

Comment: I don’t see any use of Box in your new code.  You’re still trying to do the work of a LayoutManager yourself.  It’s complex work, and you’ll be better off letting Box (or another layout manager) do it.

Comment: I tried your method, it doesn't even show up the text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206194/discussion-between-rokoblox-and-vgr).